# Acer Aspire 1694 not charging

Tags: hardware-failure, acer-aspire, laptop-repair

I've a Acer Aspire 1694WLMi and it just stopped working.

When the charger is connected, its (the charger) green LED indicator starts flashing repeatedly but there's no life signal from the laptop. On the other hand, when I disconnect the charger from the laptop but keep it plugged to AC power the LED stops flashing.

What could it be?